# Sort HashMap according to order of insertion

Tags: javascript, sorting, hashmap

Assuming I have the following array

> [5,5,2,2,1]

I wish to count the number of times each number appear hence I store the count in a hashmap

```
  arr = [5,5,2,2,1]
  var counter = {}
  for ( var i in arr)
  {
      var value = arr[i]
      counter[value] = (counter[value] || 0) + 1

  }
```

The hashmap  looks like this

> { '1': 1, '2': 2, '5': 2 }

The hashmap is sorted according to the key.

I am wondering how do you sort hashmap according to key and **then sort by order of insertion for keys which has the same value(value as in key value pair)**

For the above example, I want to get the following array

> { '1': 1, '5': 2, '2': 2 }

Though '5' and '2' have the same value(value as in key value pair), '5' is inserted before '2' hence it should come first

Comment: Hashmaps (or "objects", in JS) are not intended for use where sorting is necessary. If you need it to be sorted use an array. Perhaps instead of storing just the count as the value you could store an object with a `count` and `order` property, then use that to create an array in the right order.

Comment: What you're calling a hashmap, in JavaScript is just an object, and they are not ordered. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Object.keys(counter).sort(), suppose you do another one for the values